# How to configure Mysql to avoid an error: Illegal mix of collations

Tags: mysql, django

Every time I run the django unit test, a test database is created. During the test, I encounter an error

```
django.db.utils.DatabaseError: (1267, "Illegal mix of collations (latin1_swedish_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_general_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation '='")
```

I know there's a solution for a production database.

Is it possible to override the mysql configuration so that the correct encoding is applied by default to each new test database?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution

1. go to  */etc/mysql/my.cnf*
2. add

   [mysql]
   default-character-set=utf8mb4

   [mysqld]
   character-set-server=utf8mb4
   collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
3. restart mysql

   service mysql restart